# Encapsulated event handling with Enums

Tags: java, enums

My Application Layer/View has a event dispatching system aka blackboard. In it listeners are stored by a hashmap with keys being event types implemented as an enum EventType and values being the listener references listening to this event type. E.g. a model object is listening to event type "LOCAL_PLAYER_INPUT", blackboard processes and notifies the player since player implements EventHandler interface.

I would like to decouple my model further by implementing a standalone blackboard for model. It would then be added as a listener to the application layer blackboard since application layer is getting I/O from keyboard or touch. Model blackboard would itself delegate events further then.
For this I wanted to create an enum hierachy where the event is categorized in this manner:

```
MODEL.LOCAL.PLAYER_INPUT
```

Model would be registered as listener in view blackboard only by passing MODEL like this:

```
addListener(model.blackboard, MODEL); //Types: (EventHandler, EventType)
```

By combining interfaces with enums I achieved, that I can write eventtypes like MODEL.X.Y but it won't be accepted by addListener although MODEL is implementing EventType interface.

**What should I do?**

*EDIT: Some more code*

addListener Method:

```
    public void addListener(EventHandler handler, EventType eventType) {
    getListener(eventType).add(handler);}


private Array<EventHandler> getListener(EventType eventType) {
    if(map.containsKey(eventType))
        return map.get(eventType);
    else {
        Array<EventHandler> tmp = new Array<EventHandler>(false, 1, EventHandler.class);
        map.put(eventType, tmp);
        return tmp;
    }

}
```

Enums:

```
public interface WL extends EventType {

public static enum LOCAL {
    PLAYER_INPUT,
    NPC_INPUT
}
```

}

GameEvent:

```
    public GameEvent(EventType eventType, Object message) {
    this.eventType = eventType;
    this.message = message;
    timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

}
```

Comment: Since your keys are enums, you should consider using an `EnumMap`. Although I believe this is not really performance critical here

Comment: That is a nice tip, I will implement it, thanks!

Comment: Some more code would be helpful. How do your enum(s) look like, what's the compiler complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

`MODEL.LOCAL.PLAYER_INPUT` is not of type `EventType` even though `MODEL` is. As the enum is an inner class of `MODEL`, it's type is acctually `LOCAL`.

```
public interface WL extends EventType { // Your interface WL is EventType

    public static enum LOCAL { // Your enum is type LOCAL because there are no extensions
        PLAYER_INPUT,
        NPC_INPUT // Your enum constants represents something of type LOCAL
    }
}
```

You could change it to:

```
public enum WL implements EventType { // Your interface WL is EventType

    public static enum LOCAL implements EventType { // LOCAL is now EventType
        PLAYER_INPUT,
        NPC_INPUT // So are the enum constants
    }
}
```

The problem is, if you now refer to `WL.LOCAL`, it's type would be `Class` (not 100% sure about that one but it's deffinetly not `EventType`. Might not even compile acctually). You would have to declare `LOCAL` as an enum constant to access it that way. Sadly there is no way to do this if both should have the same name.

If I'm not missing something you'd have to find an entirely different solution. Might not be the answer you were looking for but was too long to put into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I'm going for this way now:

Since enum WL (this is short for WorldLogic, that's the name for my model) is of Type WL I could do a getClass() check and everythings fine. Add a overloaded addListener Method to my blackboard which adds listeners looking for a special class and that's it.